# Why doesn't thunderbird appear in the application switcher?

Tags: unity, thunderbird

When I switch applications with [Alt+Tab], I don't see thunderbird as one of the options.
Also, and I assume it's related, the Thunderbird icon in the unity bar isn't coloured and doesn't have the little triangle indicator that it is running, even though the inbox window is open.

What is going on here? Does thunderbird have some different status? Is it related to the integration with the notifications thingy in the top panel? Is there some setting I can change that makes thunderbird more visible (at the moment I have to use Compiz-Scale to see the Inbox window.

Any help/explanation appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer but I can confirm that Thunderbird shouldn't have any different 'status' causing this. It should work just like any other application. Has it been like this since you installed or did it go like this after a change such as an update?

Comment: I haven't changed anything, but have only recently started using Thunderbird.
I can't remember for sure, but I have a feeling that the first day I used it (2days ago), it appeared in the side bar like a normal app. I pinned it there, so I guess it must have appeared. Now I have unpinned it, and it no longer appears in the sidebar when it is open. 
Also have the feeling that this changed at the same time as the notifications started appearing in the little envelope menu in the panel.

Answer (score 2):

I've only just installed ubuntu 12.04 and noticed the same strange behavior: Thunderbird doesn't show up in [Alt+Tab] and neither in the launcher. 
I get Thunderbird back by clicking on the "envelope notifications thingy" and then on "Mail" - and Thunderbird is back on the screen (I don't use Compiz). Thunderbird is set as the default email client. 
On the other hand there is no problem at all on my other laptop with an equally brand new Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I'm clueless as to why it should work on one laptop but not on the other.